# How to lock pages for non-logged users

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How can i do so when a user try's to access index.php when there not logged in get's redirected to login.php ?

**EDIT**

I havent tried anything, i only have the code for logged in users

Comment: Show code of what you have tried

Comment: i havent tried anything, i only have the code for logged in users

Comment: Have you tried searching stack overflow or Google before asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a session varaiable set:

```
// Required to set and read sessions
session_start();
// Conditional if logged in
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        // do logged in stuff
    }
else 
    // Redirect if not logged in
    header("Location: login.php");
```

Comment: thanks dude, i'll accept in 9 minutes :)

Comment: You should `exit();` the script to prevent leaking any code to a user that's not logged in. (see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

When you start a user's session, set a `$_SESSION` variable:

```
/* login_submit.php */

// Check if username and password are correct
if ($username == $valid_username && $password == $valid_password) {
    session_start(); // Start the session
    $_SESSION["session_secret"] = "a_secret_string"; // Set a secret variable
    header("Location: index.php"); // Redirect the user to index.php
}
```

Then, check for that variable to see if a user is logged in:

```
/* index.php */

// Resume the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in
if ($_SESSION["session_secret"] != "a_secret_string") {
    // Nope! This user is NOT logged in!
    header("Location: login.php"); // Redirect the user to login.php
    exit(); // Exit the script so code doesn't get leaked
}

// Code for logged in users goes below
```

Remember to destroy the session (which will destroy all session variables) when the user logs out using `session_destroy();`